Adding Smooth by Angle to an object with python
I want to add the "Smooth by Angle" modifier to a list of objects. So far I have figured out the modifier is a NODES modifier, aka Geometry Nodes, and that it uses a node_tree called "Smooth by Angle". However, this node tree does not exists in the blend file. It exists in an asset called ESSENTIALS.
The tool tip when adding the "Smooth by Angle" Modifier says this:
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add_node_group(asset_library_type='ESSENTIALS', asset_library_identifier="", relative_asset_identifier="geometry_nodes\\smooth_by_angle.blend\\NodeTree\\Smooth by Angle")

This is the code I have set up so far.
for obj in rig_objects:
    nodes = obj.modifiers.new("Smooth by Angle", 'NODES')
    nodes.node_group = # How to get the smooth by angle node tree?
    # Set Angle to 70

How do I do this?

I managed to find a way to accomplish what I wanted with bpy.ops.object.modifier_add_node_group.
def add_smooth_by_angle():
    active_object = bpy.context.active_object
    rig_objects = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.parent == active_object]
    angle = math.radians(70)
    for obj in rig_objects:
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add_node_group(
            asset_library_type='ESSENTIALS', 
            asset_library_identifier="", 
            relative_asset_identifier="geometry_nodes\\smooth_by_angle.blend\\NodeTree\\Smooth by Angle")
        obj.modifiers["Smooth by Angle"]["Input_1"] = angle
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = active_object

The problem with the above code is that calling on blenders operations costs a lot. When dealing with a large amount of objects it can take seconds to execute.
Here's an improved version that has faster execution time, because it only calls on the operation once.
def add_smooth_by_angle():
    active_object = bpy.context.active_object
    rig_objects = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.parent == active_object]
    angle = math.radians(70)
    
    has_node_group = False
    node_group = None
 
    for obj in rig_objects:
        if not has_node_group:
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_add_node_group(asset_library_type='ESSENTIALS', asset_library_identifier="", relative_asset_identifier="geometry_nodes\\smooth_by_angle.blend\\NodeTree\\Smooth by Angle")
            smooth_by_angle = obj.modifiers["Smooth by Angle"]
            smooth_by_angle["Input_1"] = angle
            node_group = smooth_by_angle.node_group
            has_node_group = True
        else:
            smooth_by_angle = obj.modifiers.new("Smooth by Angle", 'NODES')
            smooth_by_angle.node_group = node_group
            smooth_by_angle["Input_1"] = angle
        
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = active_object

When I tested the first solution I got an execution time of 5+ seconds. When I tested the second solution the execution time dropped down to less than a second. It felt snappy to execute. I left both solutions in the answer to illustrate the importance of not only finding a solution, but also making it run quickly.
